# What's the best house wrap to use underneath hardiplank (fiber cement) sidings?

Tags: siding, moisture, house-wrap

We live on a busy street near Midtown Atlanta and are currently having our home renovated. We're going to replace the wood sidings with HardiPlanks (fiber cement) sidings. What house wrap would be best to use underneath hardiplank sidings? We're looking to use it for the front of the house, and since the busy street can be quite noisy, we're hoping to use a house wrap that has soundproofing capabilities as well, if possible. Below is a photo of what's currently installed on the front of the house.
[image: This is the house wrap currently installed on the front of the house]

Comment: Looks like the insubstantial fibrous sheathing used in the 1970s and before. If so, this would be a good time to replace it with OSB sheathing then put HardiWrap over that.

Comment: Fiberboard sheathing was used into the 90s (and maybe beyond) for walls that didn't require shear bracing. I don't think it needs to be replaced.

Comment: Rats can chew right through fiberboard, but don't seem to go through plywood and OSB. Some houses from the 1970s that I have seen being extensively remodeled so the fiberboard has been exposed are riddled with rat holes. Of course if the whole house is sheathed with fiber board and only part is being resided, then does it make sense to replace the sheathing on only part of the house? And plywood and OSB are expensive right now.

Comment: At 50 bucks a sheet now is perhaps the best of times and the worst of times to replace the sheathing

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you install your siding according to ALL the manufacturers instructions, including the house wrap. See the [Hardi specifications](https://www.jameshardiepros.com/getattachment/513223b4-054b-4112-ab6b-38974c62c9cb/hardieplank-hz5-us-en.pdf).

If you notice, the third item under “General Requirements” requires you to use a house wrap that is approved by the Building Department...which includes “HardiWrap”.

Using HardiWrap will assist in your sound control issue too. HardiWrap has small protrusions across the face of the moisture barrier which keeps the siding slightly away from the wall and allows moisture to “drain” down behind the siding. This “space”will help the STC rating of your wall...although I doubt the wall is the “weak link” in your sound control system. (I’d look at lack of operable window flashing, outlets on either side of the wall, etc. that create weak links in the sound control barrier.) There are some exceptions, like in very cold climates where the water can freeze and expand, so that’s why they say “approved by the Building Department”.

We know siding leaks, that’s why we use house wrap. We’ve now learned that water must escape too. So, the manufacturer now requires caulking at the jambs and sill, but not at the head of doors and windows. This allows water to run down the wall and escape and not get trapped at the head.